# creating a login page with some username and password using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, authentication

Creating a login page using jquery which onclick to login button first gives a popup with some terms with a "ok" button it. when user clicks on it that must go to the next page.

Demo app flow that im trying:
-User opens the app
-app loads and shows a login page with username & passwords fields with login button
-user enter demo username and password lets say username: demo & password: testing and clicks on login button
-A popup comes with terms & conditions with a "ok" button in it.
-user clicks on "ok" and it goes to secondpage.html.

can this be done using jquery or javascript using html5 and css3. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick fiddle which hopefully achieves what you are looking for, you can view it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nBBUe/).

The script relies on a hidden div (`#warning`) which contains your terms and conditions.  When the user completes the required fields (I included some basic validity checking), the hidden div is set to visible allowing the user to click "Yes" or "No."  In my app, I have it show an alert when the user agrees, however in yours you can adapt this to whatever next step is necessary.